# Using both front cameras of Vive Pro with OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv, htc-vive

I seek to use the two cameras in the front of my HTC Vive Pro in order to implement SLAM using Stereo Vision. I would prefer if this was possible using Python, however, I cannot find a good way to open up both cameras (I can only open the right camera with `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`). The device is currently simply connected by a usb.

What I have so far is

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("Camera 1")
cv2.namedWindow("Camera 2")

stereo = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if stereo.isOpened():
    rval, frame = stereo.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    rval_left, left = stereo.retrieve(0)
    rval_right, right = stereo.retrieve(1)
    cv2.imshow("Camera 1", left)
    cv2.imshow("Camera 2", right)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: 
        # exit on ESC
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But `stereo` is not really stereo as expected. `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` is the laptop webcam and all other `cv2.VideoCapture(...)` returns None. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://www.vive.com/us/support/vive-pro-hmd/category_howto/activating-the-dual-camera.html#activating-the-dual-camera)

Answer (score 0):

It seems by default the camera is set to capture at 640x480 resolution, but it does support 640x960 resolution (see: [this](https://forum.htc.com/topic/9453-opencv-video-processing-with-srworks/?do=findComment&comment=55524) and [this](https://forum.htc.com/topic/16703-how-to-access-the-front-stereo-pair-for-vive-pro-with-c-on-linux/#comment-55331)).

A simple solution is below.

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("Camera 1")
cv2.namedWindow("Camera 2")

stereo = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
width = stereo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = stereo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
print(f"default size: {width} x {height}")

stereo.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, width)
stereo.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, height*2)

while stereo.isOpened():
    rval, frame = stereo.read()
    if not rval:
        break
    left  = frame[int(height):, :, ...]
    right = frame[:int(height), :, ...]
    cv2.imshow("Camera 1", left)
    cv2.imshow("Camera 2", right)
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: 
        # exit on ESC
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```